# Getting eye space point from a depth texture

Tags: opengl, glsl

I am beginning to add deferred shading to my game engine, I am having some trouble understanding how to retrieve eye space coordinates from a depth texture.

I have read about two methods in [this post](http://mynameismjp.wordpress.com/2009/03/10/reconstructing-position-from-depth/) and by my understanding:

- The first method will work if I store my depth in a `GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT` to my Framebuffer.
- The second method requires me to calculate my depth in my Shader, and store it in a `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENTn`.

The reconstruction for this second method seems too complicated for what I need, so I would rather not use that if possible.

For reconstructing eye coordinates, the first method takes the *texture coordinates, depth*, and a `w` of `1.0` in a `vec4`, multiplies that by the *inverse perspective matrix*, then divides the result by its `w`.

Will this method work unaltered with the depth stored in my `GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT` texture, and will it be accurate enough to do lighting on?

If it won't work unaltered, then what do I need to do with my depth to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you might calculate the depth in the shader and store it in a color buffer is that the depth buffer is non-linear. Due to perspective correction, you have to do extra things to a sampled depth value in order to get linear depth (which you want for view/world space position reconstruction).

It is tempting to write a linear value to `gl_FragDepth` as a solution, and I have seen some tutorials even do this... but do not do this! It destroys modern hardware depth buffer optimizations like hierarchical z-buffering and early depth testing.

The second approach that you pointed out is not only needlessly complicated, it is also horribly inefficient. You are better off simply linearizing the non-linear depth buffer during reconstruction. A few extra fragment shader instructions should be quicker than writing the depth to two locations (implicit write to the depth buffer, plus one to a dedicated color buffer) during your G-Buffer creation.

Comment: I found this while trying to render my depth buffer: http://www.ozone3d.net/blogs/lab/20090206/how-to-linearize-the-depth-value/. Will this linearize the depth the way you describe?

Comment: @jbills: Yes, that is exactly what you need to do to produce a linear depth value.

Comment: Thanks, after linearizing it, can I follow the steps I described earlier?

Comment: @jbills: No, the steps you described are for arriving at a view position through un-projection. With a linear depth value, all you need to do is multiply the depth by a ray cast from the near plane through the far plane. This is explained in the article you posted. The reason I suggest linearizing the depth value rather than skipping it and going the un-projection route is that other post-processing effects you might use in a deferred shading graphics engine work better with linear depth.

Comment: If I understand it correctly I need to get a ray that passes through where the point would be in eye space, and multiply that ray by the depth. This ray is retrieved by getting a ray to the point on the far plane that corresponds to the first vertex of your fullscreen quad, and then interpolating. Am I correct?

Comment: @jbills: Sort of, but the way it really works is you define the frustum corners per-vertex in your quad and this value is interpolated during rasterization. Then when you access the interpolated variable in your fragment shader, it corresponds nicely to a point in view-space that lies on the far plane at your screen-space (fragment location) position. This way you can take the 2D fragment coordinate and a depth value and reconstruct a full 3D position.